# Delegate that selects a writable property on a generic

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

In the following contrived example, I have a collection of `PropertyManager`s that each contains selector and assigner delegates to read from and write to a property on the generic type. It feels clunky for lots of reasons, not least of which is that both delegates are basically there to serve the same purpose: To identify the property on the generic that I want to read from then write back into.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace Tests
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class ReadWritePropertySelectorTests
    {
        public void Round<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection,
            params PropertyManager<T>[] propertyManagers)
        {
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                foreach (var propertyManager in propertyManagers)
                {
                    var valueToRound = propertyManager.Selector(item);
                    propertyManager.Assigner(item, Math.Round(valueToRound, 1));
                }
            }
        }
        public class PropertyManager<T>
        {
            public Func<T, decimal> Selector { get; set; }
            public Action<T, decimal> Assigner { get; set; }
        }
        public class Combatant
        {
            public decimal Attack { get; set; }
            public decimal Defense { get; set; }
            public decimal Health { get; set; }
        }
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            // Arrange
            var combatants = new[]
            {
                new Combatant { Attack = 33.12M, Defense = 12.771M, Health = 60.1181M }
            };

            // Act
            Round(combatants,
                new PropertyManager<Combatant>
                {
                    Selector = c => c.Attack, Assigner = (c, v) => c.Attack = v
                },
                new PropertyManager<Combatant>
                {
                    Selector = c => c.Defense, Assigner = (c, v) => c.Defense = v
                },
                new PropertyManager<Combatant>
                {
                    Selector = c => c.Health, Assigner = (c, v) => c.Health = v
                });

            // Assert
            var array = combatants.ToArray();
            Assert.AreEqual(33.1M, array[0].Attack);
            Assert.AreEqual(12.8M, array[0].Defense);
            Assert.AreEqual(60.1M, array[0].Health);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to redo this to make the call to `Round()` more concise, preferably removing the need for a strongly typed `PropertyManager`? I think ultimately calling it as follows would be awesome, but I can't figure out the language constructs to use to get there:

```
Round(combatants, c => c.Attack, c => c.Defense, c => c.Health);
```

Comment: Why are you testing a function of your test class?

Comment: Because it's a "contrived example".

Answer (score 3):

Yup, it is possible, but you'll have to delve into the dark world of [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).

This function creates getter and setter functions using the `out` parameters. It's ugly, and you usually don't want to use two `out` parameters, but hopefully it'll get you moving in the right direction.

```
public static bool CreateGetterSetter<T, V>(Expression<Func<T, V>> getterExpression, out Func<T, V> getter, out Action<T, V> setter)
{
    if (getterExpression == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("getterExpression");

    var memberExpression = getterExpression.Body as MemberExpression;
    if (memberExpression == null || memberExpression.NodeType != ExpressionType.MemberAccess || memberExpression.Member == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("The expression must get a member (property or field).", "getterExpression");

    // The expression passed in is the getter, so just compile it.
    getter = getterExpression.Compile();

    // The setter function takes two parameters as input.
    var paramT = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var paramV = Expression.Parameter(typeof(V));

    // Create the setter function
    if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Field)
    {
        // The getter retrieves a field. 
        var field = memberExpression.Member as FieldInfo;
        if (field == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not get field info for member " + memberExpression.Member.ToString());

        // This expression represents the field on the parameter.
        var fieldExpr = Expression.Field(paramT, field);

        // This expression is what the field will be set to.
        Expression rightExpr;
        if (paramV.Type == field.FieldType)
            rightExpr = paramV;
        else
            rightExpr = Expression.Convert(paramV, field.FieldType);

        // This is the assignment expression (sets the field to the parameter value).
        var assign = Expression.Assign(fieldExpr, rightExpr);

        // Compile the expressions into a lambda.
        setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, V>>(assign, paramT, paramV).Compile();
    }
    else if (memberExpression.Member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
    {
        // The getter retrieves a property.
        var property = memberExpression.Member as PropertyInfo;
        if (property == null)
            throw new ArgumentException("Could not get property info for member " + memberExpression.Member.ToString());

        // This expression represents what the property will be set to.
        Expression paramSet;
        if (paramV.Type == property.PropertyType)
            paramSet = paramV;
        else
            paramSet = Expression.Convert(paramV, property.PropertyType);

        // Handle read-only properties (have no setter).
        if (!property.CanWrite)
        {
            setter = (t, v) => Debug.Write("Cannot set read-only property: " + property.ToString());
            return false;
        }

        // This expression represents calling the property setter.
        var call = Expression.Call(paramT, property.SetMethod, paramSet);

        // Compile the expressions into a lambda.
        setter = Expression.Lambda<Action<T, V>>(call, paramT, paramV).Compile();
    }
    else
    {
        // The member was not a field or a property.
        setter = (t, v) => Debug.Write("Setter invoked for invalid expression");
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Usage:

```
public class A
{
    public string Property { get; set;}
}

// Define the variables to hold the out parameters.
Func<A, string> getter;
Action<A, string> setter;

// Call function to use expression trees to create the getter and setter.
CreateGetterSetter<A, string>(a => a.Property, out getter, out setter);

// Now you can use "getter" to get A.Property...
var inst = new A { Property = "value" };
var value = getter(inst); // value = "value"

// ... and "setter" to set A.Property...
setter(inst, "new"); // inst.Property = "new"
value = getter(inst); // value = "new";
```

And to implement Round this way...

```
public static void Round<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection, params Expression<Func<T, decimal>>[] getterExpressions)
{
    // Create all the lambdas up-front. This is expensive, so you should cache this somewhere rather than 
    // re-compiling all the expressions every time.
    var gettersSetters = new Tuple<Func<T, decimal>, Action<T, decimal>>[getterExpressions.Length]; 
    for(int i=0;i<getterExpressions.Length;i++)
    {
        Func<T, decimal> getter;
        Action<T, decimal> setter;
        CreateGetterSetter<T, decimal>(getterExpressions[i], out getter, out setter);
        gettersSetters[i] = Tuple.Create(getter, setter);
    }

    foreach (var item in collection)
    {
        foreach (var tuple in gettersSetters)
        {
            var getter = tuple.Item1;
            var setter = tuple.Item2;

            var value = getter(item);
            value = Math.Round(value, 1);
            setter(item, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: You could combine the branches for property and field using `Expression.PropertyOrField()`.